# Naming a text file and the having it display a average using functions

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ compiler called Online GDB. I need to write a program that asks the user for a file name then reads from this data to calculate an average then displays the data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
// functions 
string getFileInfo();
double calculateMean (string fileName);

// main    
int main ()
{
string filename = getFileInfo(); // getting file name 
double mean = calculateMean( filename); // avg
cout << "The mean was" << endl;
return 0;
}
// function for getting file 
string getFileInfo() {
    string filename;
    ifstream inputFile; // varibles
    // asking user for the name
    cout << "Please enter a file name to read from: ";
    cin >> filename;

   inputFile.open(filename);
   // opening name and checking if its good.
   if (inputFile)
   {
       inputFile.close();
   }
   // if the file is not good 
   else
   {
    cout << "Error: Please enter a file name to read from: ";
    cin >> filename;
   }
    return 0;
}

// funtion for mean 
double calculateMean(string fileName) 
{
    ifstream infile;
    float num=0;
    float total = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    infile.open(fileName);
    // While infile successfully extracted numbers from the stream
    while(infile >> num) {
        total += num;
        ++count;
    }
    // don't need the file anymore, close it
    infile.close();

    // give the average
   return total/count;
}
```

My part for finding the average is working but I am having trouble with the naming of the file.

It runs and it asks me for the name and when I enter it goes straight to the error and input again and then it displays this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid 
Aborted.
```

I have never seen this before and I have tried creating a file and if I don't then nothing displays.

Comment: `string getFileInfo() { ... return 0; }` Why is this returning `0`? It should be returning the filename.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that and then working on it I fixed my issue with the cout on displaying the average I realized I needed to put in the variable total/count over the return total/count; .

Comment: technically you are introducing a race condition for the file, you open the file but later you open it again assuming it is there. between these two actions the file may have been deleted/renamed. why not first read the name, then call calculateMean which checks if file exists and returns an error if not?

Answer (score -1):

This code is fully working

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    //int calculatorMin(string fileName);
    //void displayInfo(double mean, int main);
    string getFileInfo();
    double calculateMean (string fileName);

    // main    
    int main ()
    {
    string filename = getFileInfo(); // getting file name 
    double mean = calculateMean( filename); // avg
    return 0;
    }
    // function for getting file 
    string getFileInfo() {
        string filename;
        ifstream inputFile;

        cout << "Please enter a file name to read from: ";
        cin >> filename;

       inputFile.open(filename);

       if (inputFile)
       {
           inputFile.close();
       }

       else
       {
        cout << "Error: Please enter a file name to read from: ";
        cin >> filename;
       }
        //if it opens then name is good and close file then return name
        //if it didn't open, ask for a new name.
        return filename;
    }

    // funtion for mean 
    double calculateMean(string fileName) 
    {
        ifstream infile;
        float num=0;
        float total = 0.0;
        int count = 0;
        infile.open(fileName);
        // While infile successfully extracted numbers from the stream
        while(infile >> num) {
            total += num;
            ++count;
        }
        // don't need the file anymore, close it
        infile.close();
           cout << "The mean was " << total/count << endl;
        // give the average
       return total/count;

    }
```